# Modelica Discrete Semantics

Tags: semantics, modelica

I am trying to understand the Modelica semantics for a discrete signal. Given a step signal that instantaneously transitions from 0.0 to 1.0 with infinite slope at t = 0.5. Then let's say you also have a when statement as in the following code:

```
model test_discrete
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput q(start = -1.0);
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Step step(
    height=1,
    offset=0,
    startTime=0.5)

algorithm 
  when time >= 0.5 and time <= 0.5 then
    q := step.y;
  end when;
equation 
end test_discrete;
```

My question is whether q will be 0.0 or 1.0? Lets assume q is initialized to -1. When I implement the code, it transitions to 1.0, but my confusion is that 0.0 would also satisfy the equation. So I am just wondering if there are any rules to prevent non-determinant behavior. If someone could help or point me to any literature, that would be greatly appreciated! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a few comments.  First, your code is non-deterministic.  There are no assurances about the order of events that are not somehow tied to each other through a common "cause".  There are features in Modelica 3.3 to make your system synchronous (which removes the ambiguities).  But you'll have to read the specification for that.

But I'd also like to point out what is essentially an error in your code.  You say:

```
when time >= 0.5 and time <= 0.5 then
  q := step.y;
end when;
```

My guess is that you are trying to set the value of `q` at the same "instant" that `step.y` is set (and then further wondering which gets resolved first).  But this is not how a `when` statement works.  I suspect you are trying to represent the "instant" that `step.y` gets set as `time >= 0.5 and time <= 0.5`.  But that is not correct.  The instant it gets set is `time >= 0.5` alone.  The key point here is the `when` is not the same as `if`.

To put this a bit more formally, the equation inside the when clause becomes active **when** the condition associated with the `when` clause becomes true.  This is really beyond the scope of your question, but you should familiarize yourself with the differences between `when` and `if`, because this are very important semantics.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That was my thinking as well, it is non-deterministic. Regarding the when statement, yes, I agree and understand the difference between an if statement. I am new to Modelica and was naturally thinking in terms of a traditional if statement without realizing it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

My instinct tells me that you may need a pre() for the conditions, but it's just my guess.

Comment: It turns out `pre` doesn't play a role here.  The `pre` operator always applies to the current event.  Because of the asynchronous nature of `when` in this case, the event that sets `step.y` and the event that sets `q` are decoupled.  As such, `pre(step.y)` is the same as `step.y` in this context.