# When and If in Modelica

Tags: logic, modelica

Hi I have some puzzles about event and when in Modelica. Below is my code:

```
model test
  Integer bar(start=5, fixed=true);
equation 
  when (time < 2) then
    bar = 1;
  end when;
  annotation(experiment(StopTime=3));
end test;
```

My question is why I got 5 instead of 1 when time is less than 2? How can I understand the event(time < 2) in this case? What is the difference of when clause in Modelica and other programming language, like c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tobias' answer is correct.  But I think for beginners it might be a little daunting to invoke the `pre` construct or send them to the specification.  So in addition to Tobias' answer, I would point the interested reader to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014281/modelica-discrete-semantics) as well as [this chapter](http://book.xogeny.com/behavior/discrete/) in my book.  Of specific interest (I suspect) would be [this subsection](http://book.xogeny.com/behavior/discrete/when/) on `when` and how it is different from `if`.

Answer (score 2):

The `when` equation is only active when the condition **becomes** true. In your case the condition `time < 2` is true from the beginning and only becomes false.

The `when`-block can be intentionally translated to

```
b = time < 2;

if not(pre(b)) and b then
  bar = 1;
else
  bar = pre(bar);
end
```

For further information you can consult the specification https://modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec33Revision1.pdf.

Comment: your mean BECOME, which indicates the condition should change from FALSE to TRUE. Thanks.

Comment: @user3658215 Yes, the emphasis of 'become' is important. Thanks for the remark. I modified the answer in this regard.